# Visual C# Express 2010 Shortcut to comment a code block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for the equivalent of VS2010's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on Express edition

Comment: Look at options->environment->keyboard Edit.CommentSection commands shortcut. If there is noting assigned - assign it

Comment: To those for whom ctrl+c,e works, this was before the latest distribution available today I guess. It is not true anymore with a fresh Express Download (Well, that is my guess since I did not override any default setting)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C //comment
Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U //uncomment
```

Try this combinations.

Comment: Could it be that you selected a different configuration at startup?  The shortcuts mentioned above have been standard for the "C# developer settings" for as long as I can remember...

Comment: Either way they're terrible shortcuts. They need a serious rehash.

Comment: Why they couldn't make the comment and uncomment command the same is beyond me.  The people at JetBrains use 'Shift' + 'Ctrl' + '/' for both commenting and uncommenting.

Answer (score 11):

Don't have Express installed but I would assume you can customize it in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard, then search for Edit.CommentSelection (or Edit.UncommentSelection).

[image]

Comment: Wow nice! I was looking for this for ages

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>MSDN</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Sign Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Pay Money</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Download/Install VS2010</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>?

Seriously though, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> works fine for me in Express edition. You might want to reset to defaults in options.

You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to comment, if you configured your default settings differently on first launch.

Comment: Very Funny :-) Seriously, I Already bought a VS2010 Pro License. I use C# Express on the server just for testing/deploying purposes. BTW, Ctrl|E Ctrl|C is not working and the install is full default.